# Jquery-AutoComplete Shows No Results

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using Jquery-UI 1.10.4 ,but while using Autocomplete with below code it shows nothing as result:

```
$(document).on('keyup',"#txtQualityNo",function(){
            if($(this).val().length>2){

            $("#txtQualityNo").autocomplete({

            source: [{stockid:'1',qualityno:"322323",shadeno:"342"},{stockid:"2",qualityno:"122323",shadeno:"322"}],
            dataType:"json",
            focus: function( event, ui ) {

            $( "#txtQualityNo" ).val( ui.item.shadeno );
             return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {

             $( "#txtQualityNo" ).val( ui.item.shadeno );

            return false;
             }
            })
            .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {

            return $( "<li>" )
            .data( "ui-autocomplete-item", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.qualityno + "<br>" + item.shadeno + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
        };
    }
})`
```

But It shows no result.
But If I use source as project like:

```
`var projects = [
      {
        value: "jquery",
        label: "jQuery",
        desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
        icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
      },
      {
        value: "jquery-ui",
        label: "jQuery UI",
        desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
        icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
      },
      {
        value: "sizzlejs",
        label: "Sizzle JS",
        desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
        icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
      }
    ];`
```

then it works fine..
I don't know what silly mistake I am making as I have used Autocomplete several times before.

Comment: Take a good look at http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ and you will find the answers you seek. Also, there's an extra closing bracket.

Comment: Which one?May be while pasting code it may have been missed out as it shows no error

Comment: Ohk Got it as I am using local Array,need to use label and value..